# Asynchronous or multiprocess for read/write several files

Tags: python, asynchronous, io, multiprocessing, pool

I have several txt files and I need to get several xml files.

I wrote a function `def write_data(txt_path: str)` which build a structure of xml file, read txt file from hdd, insert txt data to xml structure and write it to hdd.

```py
def write_data(txt_path: str):
    # build xml skeleton
    root = etree.Element(...)
    h1 = etree.SubElement(root, ...)
    h2 = etree.SubElement(h1, ...)

    def insert_txt_data(data: str):
        h3 = etree.SubElement(h2, ...)
        id = etree.SubElement(h3, ...)
        id.text = data

    for data in get_data_from_path(txt_path): 
        insert_txt_data(data)
    
    # write xml to hdd
    t = etree.ElementTree(root)
    t.write()
```

Now I call this function with Pool and it's work quickly:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(10) as p:
        p.map(write_data, get_path(arr_path))
```

But this implementation consumes a lot of memory. It might be worthwhile to use asynchronous, or it's a bad idea? What should I use in this case, `Pool` or `async`? And what would be the advantages of asynchronous style? I'm really confused by this question.

P.S Xml file size from 300 MB to 2 GB

Comment: For the same reason you (presumably) chose multiprocessing over multithreading, i.e. `write_data` does a fair amount of CPU-intensive work, asynchronous would not be as performant. Yet, you do not show *how* you do your xml processing. Is there a way of doing it so you do not have to build the entire xml document in memory?

Comment: @Booboo
I build the base of xml before `insert_txt` and after this, i read txt file line by line and wrap it to xml tag. 
I think, that I should keep the entire document in memory.

_upd a code in description_